# QGIS 3.22.: automatic changes by multiedit in attribute table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.22 I have a problem with the multiedit-function in the attribute table.

In my case I have a point layer with addresses. This layer is filtered from the database to one specific street.

Now I select all features in the attribute table, enable editing for the layer and activate the multiedit mode. Immediatly the tool informs about confirmed changes of the data.
I discovered that among other attributes all housenumbers were automatically changed to the same value (e.g. '2').
When saving the changes to the layer it means that the adresses 1,2,3,4,... are overwritten to just 2.

How do I get rid of that behavior?

Downgraded meanwhile to QGIS 3.16.13 where this doesn’t happen.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want to do and how exactly your workflow looks like: what do you mean by "select all numbers in the attribute table"? You can select features, not numbers... Further: you "activate the multiedit mode" and "immediatly" data are changed? Without any intervention by you? What is your final goal?

Comment: Sorry, I ment, that I select all features (corrected it above) in the attrbute table. And yes, when I toggle multiedit mode then at the top of the form which appears with the attributes, threre is the message about confirmed changes. That's before anything done by myself. Switching back to the "normal" list in the attribute table shows then, that e.g. all adresses have the same number.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.